# past simple possible in that case

Tags: past-simple

20. I used (use) to ski when I was at the university but I broke (break) a leg five years ago and since then I have not skied (not ski) any more.

Will be possible to use past simple I did not ski any more(meaning it is forbidden for me to ski, it is too risky). A changement is not possible.

Fromhttp://www.ndj.edu.lb/sites/default/files/images/import/grade-9-all-tenses.pdf

Comment: "I have not skied" by itself is OK, but with *anymore* "I do not (don't) ski anymore."

Comment: [Please fix your sentence: Is it possible to etc., not: will be possible.]

Answer (score 1):

The "any more" is not congruous with past simple because it implies a continuum. "I *do not* ski any more" is correct in this case, or "I have not skied since".